# Checked radio button in jquery-ui dialog window

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I created simple dialog window using jquery-ui. It's look like this:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Attribute Category">
    <input type="radio" id="priceable" name="price" value="true" checked="checked"/> Priceable
    <input type="radio" id="priceless" name="price" value="false"/> Priceless
</div>
```

This code works only in Firefox.

[image]

In other browsers like Chrome or IE all radio buttons not checked.

[image]

Maybe someone can help me and give advice?

Sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATE**
add whole picture in chrome

[image]

the same dialog box in firefox

[image]

Comment: Remove  `=checked` and it should work - although your code works fine on all three browsers on my system :s

Comment: this didn't help. `although your code works fine on all three browsers` if I create simple html page and past this code into body it also work fine on my machine, but I need to create dialog window with radio buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]try:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Attribute Category">
<input type="radio" id="priceable" name="price" value="true" checked/> Priceable
<input type="radio" id="priceless" name="price" value="false"/> Priceless
</div>
```

but surprisingly your code works very fine on my system..

Comment: look at my comment below the question

Comment: without `="checked"` :p

Comment: I remove =checked but this has not any effect

Comment: I add picture of my dialog box opened in chrome. and you can see that this not help

Comment: see the picture in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Attribute Category">
<input type="radio" id="priceable" name="price" value="true" checked ="checked"> Priceable
<input type="radio" id="priceless" name="price" value="false"/> Priceless
</div>
```